# Can't remove extra row from bottom of MigLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, miglayout

I'm building a GUI using MigLayout in Java, on Eclipse Neon. My code should be providing two rows, and two columns, with a gap of 15, that grow to fill the frame when the window expands. I'm not sure why, but there is a 3rd row being automatically generated that I can't seem to get rid of. I've hard-coded the layout to two rows and columns, and tried removing the 3rd row using the swing editor. While the remove button works on rows 0 and 1, deleting them and their contents, it does nothing to the last row.

below is a picture of my code running with that pesky 3rd row

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhFHJ.jpg)

Here is my code

```
public Master() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 440, 163);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]15[grow]", "[grow]15[grow]"));

    btnDailyLog = new JButton("Daily Log");
    btnDailyLog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnDailyLog,  "spany 2,grow");


    btnEmpReports = new JButton("Employee Reports");
    btnJobReports = new JButton("Job Reports");

    contentPane.add(btnEmpReports, "grow,wrap");
    contentPane.add(btnJobReports, "grow,wrap");


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra row is due to the `wrap` instruction in `contentPane.add(btnJobReports, "grow,wrap");`
 Remove `wrap` to fix the issue:

`contentPane.add(btnJobReports, "grow");`

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Tester extends JPanel{
    public Tester(){
        super(new MigLayout("", "[grow]15[grow]", "[grow]15[grow]"));

        JButton btnDailyLog = new JButton("Daily Log");
        JButton btnEmpReports = new JButton("Employee Reports");
        JButton btnJobReports = new JButton("Job Reports");

        add(btnDailyLog,"spany 2,grow");
        add(btnEmpReports, "grow,wrap");
        add(btnJobReports, "grow");
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(440, 163);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tester");

        Tester tester = new Tester();
        frame.add(tester);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just facepalmed so hard that my hand came out through the back of my head.
For anyone reading this, having the same issue: This is the correct solution because "wrap" functions essentially the same way that a carriage return does in a text file, creating a new line.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips you are welcome! I am glad it helped :)